# Android: Take Screen Shoot for a layout

Tags: android, android-layout, android-linearlayout, android-screen

I am trying to create a **PhotoFrame** app, for that i have a frame and i add an image to that frame from gallery.This Frame is in one of the layout in the main layout am trying to take screen shoot for that layout.

**Layout.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:id="@+id/root"
tools:context="com.ccs.photoframe.MainActivity"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:weightSum="1">

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight=".1"
    android:orientation="vertical">
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn_select"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:text="Select Photo"/>

</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/layout_frame"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight=".8"
    android:background="@drawable/photo_frame"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    >
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/img_save_photo"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:visibility="gone"
       />

    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="50dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="50dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="70dp"
        >
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/ivImage"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:scaleType="matrix"/>

    </FrameLayout>
</LinearLayout>
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight=".1"
    android:orientation="horizontal">
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn_save_photo"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:text="Save Photo"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

I am trying to take screen shoot in the **LinearLayout "layout_frame"**

I tried ...

```
 btn_save_photo.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            View v1 = layout_frame.getRootView();
            v1.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
            Bitmap bm = v1.getDrawingCache();
            BitmapDrawable bitmapDrawable = new BitmapDrawable(bm);
            img_save_photo = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.img_save_photo);
            img_save_photo.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            img_save_photo.setBackgroundDrawable(bitmapDrawable);
        }
    });
```

But this taking screen shoot for the entire layout.

Is there any possible way to take screen shoot for the specific location.

Thanks in advance:)

Comment: Remove the `getRootView()` call if you just want `layout_frame`. In fact, just use `layout_frame`. You don't need `View v1`.

Comment: what do you mean by specific location ...specific view?

Comment: sorry , its specific view  @Sohail Zahid

Comment: @BinilSurendran see my answer

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can get screen shot of any view like this.

```
    ImageView redoo_btn = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.redoo_btn);
    FrameLayout paintLayout = (FrameLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawing);
    LinearLayout linearLayout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawing1);

    Bitmap bm = Takeshot(linearLayout);
    Bitmap bm = Takeshot(redoo_btn);
    Bitmap bm = Takeshot(paintLayout);

    Bitmap Takeshot(View view) {
        view.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
        view.buildDrawingCache(true);
        Bitmap b = Bitmap.createBitmap(view.getDrawingCache());
        view.setDrawingCacheEnabled(false); // clear drawing cache
//        view.setImageBitmap(b);
        return b;
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

Yes you can do this way:

```
LinearLayout mlinearlaoytfrme=(LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.layout_frame);
Bitmap mBItmap=takeScreenshotReceipt();
img_save_photo = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.img_save_photo);
img_save_photo.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
img_save_photo.setBackgroundDrawable(bitmapDrawable);

private Bitmap takeScreenshotReceipt()
{
    View v1 = getRootView().findViewById(R.id.layout_frame);
    v1.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
    return v1.getDrawingCache();
}
```

Comment: it takes the screen shoot for the root layout @Harshal Kalavadiya

Answer (score -1):

Try this method

```
public static Bitmap getBitmapFromView(View view) {
        Bitmap returnedBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(view.getWidth(),
                view.getHeight(), Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);

        Canvas canvas = new Canvas(returnedBitmap);
        Drawable bgDrawable = view.getBackground();
        if (bgDrawable != null)
            bgDrawable.draw(canvas);
        else
            canvas.drawColor(Color.WHITE);
        view.draw(canvas);
        return returnedBitmap;
    }
```